# Projecting variables in python when applying the map function

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

Is it possible to project the second argument of the inner function when mapping across a set of items in Python?

when using map with the monadic use of the int cast function it works simply:

```
list(map(int, ["4","3","1","2"]))
```

But I want to cast multiple binary digits to an int using int's dyadic form int("1101",2) using map:

```
list(map(int(,2), ["1101","0001","1100","0011"]))
```

Comment: Have you considered using a lambda?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need `lambda`

```
list(map(lambda x : int(x,2), ["1101","0001","1100","0011"]))
```

but when you need `list`, `lambda` and `map`, that's a dead giveaway that you just need *list comprehension*:

```
[int(x,2) for x in ["1101","0001","1100","0011"]]
```

(clearer, shorter, and faster than `map` when `lambda` is required)

Comment: Ah, good idea mentioned list comps. That really  is the better, more pythonic way in this case. +1

Answer (score 5):

The `int` function has signature:

```
int(x, base=10)
```

So we can make a `partial`, where we assign `base=2` to:

```
from functools import partial

list(map(partial(int, base=2), ["1101","0001","1100","0011"]))
```

`partial` takes as first parameter a function (here `int`) as well as other (named and unnamed) parameters. It constructs a function that will fill in some parameters itself.

Comment: Ah, this is also a nice idea. I forgot about `functools.partial`. +1

Answer (score 4):

If you need to pass arguments to `int`, you'll need to wrap it in a function. You can use a normal function:

```
def func(i):
    return int(i, 2)
```

Or you can use a `lambda` function definition instead:

```
lambda i: int(i, 2)
```

Your code would then be:

```
list(map(lambda i: int(i, 2), ["1101","0001","1100","0011"]))
```

However, as @Jean said, once you reach this point, you should seriously consider using a comprehension over `map` and `lambda`.